# This shower door isn't closing in the correct position. How do I fix it?

Tags: doors, shower, hinges, glass

Having a issue where this shower door swings open and doesn't stay closed. I have to take a shower with the door swinged into the shower or open letting water out. These are saloon style hinges so swinging both ways is normal.

How do I fix this? Included are a picture of where it swings

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are those saloon-style hinges with springs that ordinarily pull the door to its closed position? I don't see any door stop. Combining the door stop observation with your image of the hinge, I've deduced the saloon-style hinges. You should clarify your question instead of responding in the comments. Those hinges are called "double action" or "double acting," but I'd also use the word "saloon" for the benefit of others searching the web so they can find this thread.

Comment: Added that they are saloon style hinges in the post. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The ones in our shower have a small detent or ramp built in so it requires more pressure to get out of the valley position, but not much. You can look up gravity hinges to get a better explanation on how they work. Usually they use gravity (weight of the door helps) to bring the doors to a closed position (center). When the doors are opened, either direction they are pushed up a small incline or ramp, when released they ride back down the ramp. When at the bottom of the ramp, the doors are in the middle or closed position. With this in mind determine what is keeping them from going to the closed position. Being level is important as is proper alignment.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If that is magnetic metal framing, you could get a strong magnet put inside the spot where it is supposed to stop, otherwise, I suggest a big strip of gorilla tape.

Comment: Would you tape the door shut from the outside or inside?